# crash without error message opencv under Qt

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, terminal

I have a problem under Qt, Actually I want to use opencv under it (ubuntu) and there is a crash.
If I compile under the terminal :

g++ `pkg-config --cflags opencv` example.cc -o output_file `pkg-config --libs opencv`

All is all right but under QT there is a crashed problem and I just read this message error :

Starting /home/quentin/build-test_opencv-Desktop_Qt_5_2_1_GCC_64bit-Release/test_opencv...
The program has unexpectedly finished.
/home/quentin/build-test_opencv-Desktop_Qt_5_2_1_GCC_64bit-Release/test_opencv crashed

This is my .pro :

```
QT       += core

QT       -= gui

TARGET = test_opencv
CONFIG   += console
CONFIG   -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += opencv

SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += -I /usr/local/include/opencv

LIBS += `pkg-config opencv --libs`
```

and this is my main.cpp :

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( "lena.png" ); 

    cout << "Image WIDTH  = " << img->width << endl;
    cout << "Image HEIGHT  = " << img->height << endl;
    cvReleaseImage( &img );
    return 0;


}
```

Comment: Added to your code, after cvLoadImage("lena.png"): `assert(img != NULL)`, you will need to include `<cassert>`.

Comment: since you're new to this, - please use opencv's c++ api, avoid IplImages, cv* functions, etc. just don't start learning a deprecated api.

Comment: Notice that ` LIBS += `pkg-config opencv --libs` ` is not necessary since you are already linking to opencv when doing `CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
PKGCONFIG += opencv`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `cvLoadImage` fails and returns `nullptr`. You never bother checking for that.

Answer (score 0):

What version of openCV do you use? What berak means is that IplImage is not used in the newer versions of openCV. Use Mat instead of IplImage. Try this code and tell me what happens:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Mat* img = new cv::Mat(cv::imread("lena.png",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)); 

    if(img == NULL){
        perror("Could not load image");
    }

    std::cout << "Image WIDTH  = " << img->cols << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Image HEIGHT  = " << img->rows << std::endl;
    img->release();
    return 0;
}
```

This will work in opencv 2.4.X. Also make sure your image is in the same folder as your program. Please tell me of any error.